# SVG css background image fade in different color svg on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I want to only use one div for the icon and one css selector.

Currently I have it working with two different background images being loaded.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6r0x4npd/

[image]

html

```
<h1>Hover over the icon</h1>
<div class="icon bell"></div>
```

css

```
body {
    padding: 50px;
}

.icon {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
    background-size: 40px 40px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;    
}

.icon:hover {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
    background-size: 40px 40px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: why base64 instead of inlining the svg? You could then change the "stroke" property with CSS on hover

Comment: Using SVG as a background image makes it work like a raster. It seems rather difficult to do with a raster so it's just as difficult with SVG as a background-image.